# Unable to write a simple step passing a single string as a parameter

Tags: java, regex, cucumber

I work with JBehave on a daily basis, but have been tasked with working on a project that uses Cucumber.  In order to add a custom reporting class functionality to that project, I need to add two steps, one at the start of the feature (story) and another at the start of the scenario.   I merely want to pass to the application a description of the feature/story and the scenario to be passed to the reporting module.  I know that cucumber can access the scenario name through code, but that would only resolve one of the two lines - I would still need to have another one that passes the description of the feature/story.

What I've tried in the feature file:

```
Feature: Ecolab BDD Test Automation Demo

Scenario Outline: User can login and logout from the landing page
    Given story "EcolabWebDemo_TestCases - Ecolab BDD Test Automation Demo"
    Given scenario "User can login and logout from the landing page"
    Given I am on the Ecolab landing page
```

The corresponding code for the two added Given statements at the beginning above:

```
@Given("^story {string}$") // \"(\\S+)\"
public void givenStory(String storyName) {
    test.initStory(storyName); // will show on report in Features column
}

@Given("^scenario {string}$") // \"(\\S+)\"
public void givenScenario(String scenarioName) {
    test.initScenario(scenarioName);
}
```

The commented regex patterns afterwards are the suggested ones I should try but do not seem to work either.

The current configuration at least seems to "find" the steps but reports:

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException:
>   java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index
>   13 ^the scenario {string}$

So that's obviously not the solution.  The regex used instead of {string} simply does not find a match and does not run.

regex is absolute Greek to me, not sure why it can't just be simple like the {string} option implied it would be in the cucumber documentation.  I've been searching on-line for guidance for the better part of two days to no avail, I'm apparently not even sure what to be searching for.

Comment: Guessing u are on cucumber 3 +.. Remove the ^ at the start and $ at the end from the pattern.

Comment: Even if all the other steps have that sequence?

Comment: Wow... checking the pom.xml it was version 1.2.0

Comment: In 3 plus thre is a concept of cucumber expression which replaces regular expression. Both work when done separately but not together in the same place. U are doing the later.  U have to pick one style.

Comment: If in version 1.2 u cant use {string} stuff. Do consider upgrading to latest. Version u are trying is ancient

Comment: After a quick scan of the repository, the latest version of info.cukes (all flavors) seems to be 1.2.5

Comment: Try in io.cucumber It has been changed. Better just google cucumber 3 maven repository

Comment: The artifacts can be found at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Grasshopper's suggestion, I updated the version of Cucumber from 1.2.0 to 1.2.5.  I was prepared to change the pom.xml to use the 3.x versions but tried the latest of the specified libraries first, and it did report after an attempted run what the correct regex should be for the two steps I added.

```
@Given("^story \"([^\"]*)\"$")
```

and

```
@Given("^scenario \"([^\"]*)\"$")
```

Now that the project has a version that seems to recognize strings and also reports the missing steps, the project now runs as intended.

Thanks for your help, Grasshopper.